# ORDER by desc/desc with different LIMIT

Tags: sql

I want to check the last 20 ids from a db and show the 7 most clicked I have done anything I just cannot find how to do it I tryied many thinks an example to understand what I want...I just need order them by two desc and with different LIMIT but its not working with and and if I write it in a different line it takes the last one...

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

Or SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 and then find the 7 biggest with php and show them...

Comment: Have you tried union?

Comment: SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC , clicks DESC LIMIT 20 like this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
UNION
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7

Comment: @OnlyMultiHD, try  select * from ( select * from search order by id  desc limit 20) T order by clicks desc limit 7

Comment: That's twice you have written 'not working'. If you say it three times you hair catches on fire. Explain the issue (error message) rather than writing 'not working'

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the ordering you are trying to achieve?

Comment: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: Please specify dbms, since LIMIT is not ANSI SQL. (ANSI SQL has a FETCH FIRST construction.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also show us some sample data and the expected output. It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Maybe `LIMIT` is not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the ANSI SQL answer:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM "search" ORDER BY id DESC FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY)
ORDER BY clicks DESC FETCH FIRST 7 ROWS ONLY
```

The inner SELECT is used to get the last 20 ids. Then pick the 7 most clicked out of those 20.

If your dbms doesn't support FETCH FIRST, try LIMIT or whatever...

BTW, search is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so it should really be double quoted, i.e. "search".